# Qt : How to start , stop and delete thread?

Tags: qt, qthread

=====================OUTDATE=======================

I have a vector which contains threads, each thread is doing a while loop, for some reason, i need to delete the thread in the vector, to do this, i referenced this blog and write a test [demo online](https://onlinegdb.com/aRfxvvta7). But when i write `pthread_cancel()` in Qt, it reports error: use of undeclared identifier 'pthread_cancel'. I have added `LIBS += -lpthread` in my `.pro` file and added `#include <thread>` in my `.cpp` file, this error still exists.

=====================UPDATE=====================

Afterwards, i trid to use QThread to achieve my goal. In brief, to start a qthread, i create a `Worker` class, then instantiate it and move it to QThread, connect `&QThread::started` with `&Worker::process`, `process` is the time consuming method, finnaly call `thread->start();`; to stop a qthread, i use a bool flag, and i store it with thread id in QMap, if the bool flag is set to false, qthread will break while loop, and emit a `finished()` signal and this signal will trigger `&QThread::quit`; to delete the qthread, i connect `finished()` signal with `&Worker::deleteLater` and `&QThread::deleteLater`.
The code are:

**mainwindow.cpp**

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "worker.h"
#include <QThread>
#include <QMap>
#include <QDebug>

QMap<int, bool> stateController;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->tableWidget->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
    ui->tableWidget->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);

    qDebug()<<"Main UI thread id is"<<(int)QThread::currentThreadId();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_add_clicked()
{
    int row = ui->tableWidget->rowCount();
    ui->tableWidget->insertRow(row);
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(row,0,new QTableWidgetItem());//hold a place for blank item, in order to uniformly determine whether its text is empty afterwards
    QTableWidgetItem *ckx = new QTableWidgetItem;
    ckx->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(row,1,ckx);
}

void MainWindow::on_tableWidget_cellClicked(int row, int column)
{
    if(column == 1){
        bool state = ui->tableWidget->item(row,1)->checkState();
        if(state){
            if(ui->tableWidget->item(row,0)->text().isEmpty()){//only if there is not thread id, then create the thread
                QThread* thread = new QThread();
                qDebug()<<"New created thread id is"<<(int)thread->currentThreadId(); //I found this thread id will equal to main ui thread id, so i use a sigal/slot to update thread id
                Worker* worker = new Worker(row);
                worker->moveToThread(thread);

                connect( worker, &Worker::updateQThreadIDSignal, this, &MainWindow::updateQThreadID);

                connect( thread, &QThread::started, worker, &Worker::process);
                connect( worker, &Worker::finished, thread, &QThread::quit);

                // automatically delete thread and worker object when work is done:
                connect( worker, &Worker::finished, worker, &Worker::deleteLater);
                connect( thread, &QThread::finished, thread, &QThread::deleteLater);
                //start the thread
                thread->start();
            }
        }else{
            if(!ui->tableWidget->item(row,0)->text().isEmpty()){//only if there is already the thread, then stop it
                int thread_id = ui->tableWidget->item(row,0)->text().toInt();
//                qDebug()<<"get thread id is"<<thread_id;
                QMutexLocker locker(&mx);
                stateController[thread_id] = false;
                ui->tableWidget->setItem(row,0,new QTableWidgetItem());//Because thread will be delete later, so clear its thread id
            }
        }
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_delete_clicked()
{
    QItemSelectionModel* selectionModel = ui->tableWidget->selectionModel();
    QModelIndex index = selectionModel->currentIndex();
    if(index.isValid()){
        int row = index.row();
        if(!ui->tableWidget->item(row,0)->text().isEmpty()){//Before stop the thread, ensure it exist
            int thread_id = ui->tableWidget->item(row,0)->text().toInt();
            if(ui->tableWidget->item(row,1)->checkState() == Qt::Checked){
                //If not stopped yet, firstly stop it
                QMutexLocker locker(&mx);
                stateController[thread_id] = false;
            }
            stateController.remove(thread_id);
        }
        ui->tableWidget->removeRow(row);
    }
}

void MainWindow::updateQThreadID(int row, QString id)
{
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(row,0,new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(id.toInt())));
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMutex>
#include <vector>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_add_clicked();

    void on_tableWidget_cellClicked(int row, int column);

    void on_pushButton_delete_clicked();
public slots:
    void updateQThreadID(int row, QString id);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QMutex mx;

};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**worker.cpp**

```cpp
#include "worker.h"
#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMutexLocker>

extern QMap<int, bool> stateController;

Worker::Worker(int row) : row_index(row) {
    qDebug()<<"Create new worker at thread "<<(int)QThread::currentThreadId();
}

Worker::~Worker() {
    qDebug()<<"Destroy the worker instance";
}

void Worker::process() {
    thread_id = (int)QThread::currentThreadId();
    stateController.insert(thread_id, true);
//    qDebug()<<"set thread id is"<<thread_id;
    emit updateQThreadIDSignal(row_index,QString("%1").arg(thread_id)); //execute once, because if delete row happen, the row index will change
    while(true)
    {
        count++;
        QThread::sleep(2);//simulate time consuming operations
        qDebug()<<thread_id<<"processing"<<count;

        {//life scope of locker
            QMutexLocker locker(&mx);
            if(!stateController[thread_id])//In every loop, determine whether it can run, if not, exit the loop
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    emit finished();
}
```

**worker.h**

```cpp
#ifndef WORKER_H
#define WORKER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QMutex>

class Worker : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Worker(int row);
    ~Worker();
public slots:
    void process();
signals:
    void finished();
    void updateQThreadIDSignal(int, QString);
private:
    int thread_id;
    int row_index;
    QMutex mx;
    int count = 0;
};

#endif // WORKER_H
```

To watch the demo video, click [here](https://streamja.com/KGBry).
If you have any advice, please let me know, thanks !

Even though the codes seems to work fine, but i still have a question : Why i wrote `&Worker::deleteLater`, but I never see the destructor of Worker is called ?

Comment: It's a C function defined in <pthread.h>

Comment: Thanks for your tip ! I went to download ftp://sourceware.org/pub/pthreads-win32/pthreads-w32-2-9-1-release.zip, and configured the .pro and add #include <pthread.h>, then i wrote the code : `std::unordered_map<QString, pthread_t> ThreadMap;` `std::thread th(&Mainwindow::sendFunc, this,row,comboxBox->currentText().toDouble());` ` ThreadMap["th"] = th.native_handle();`, it reports error : `cannot convert argument of incomplete type 'std::thread::native_handle_type' (aka 'void *') to 'const ptw32_handle_t' for 1st argument`, i have no idea why these codes are alright in onlineGDB but not in Qt

Comment: I am considering using QThread now

Comment: It seems that you want to use pthread funtion (POXIS) in Windows, yes, it's better to use QThread if you want a multithreading application in Qt way.